# Stack Overflow on Random Integers

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement, math, while-loop

Where the commented section is, it says that there is a `StackOverflowError` - `null`. I am trying to get it to make random numbers to match up with an inputted value. The goal of this code is to do the following:

1. Accept a top number (ie 1000 in order to have a scale of (1-1000)).
2. Accept an input as the number for the computer to guess.
3. Computer randomly guesses the first number and checks to see if it is correct.
4. If it is not correct, it should go through a loop and randomly guess numbers, adding them to an ArrayList, until it guesses the input. It should check to see if the guess is already in the array and will generate another random number until it makes one that isn't in the list.
5. In the end, it will print out the amount of iterations with the *count* variable.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrNumGuess
{
    public static Integer top, input, guess, count;
    public static ArrayList <Integer> nums;
    public static void main ()
     {
        System.out.println("Please enter the top number");
        top = (new Scanner(System.in)).nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number to guess (1 - " + top + ")");
        input = Integer.parseInt(((new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine()).trim());
        nums = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //use nums.contains(guess);
        guess = (new Random()).nextInt(top) + 1;
        nums.add(guess);
        System.out.println("My first guess is " + guess);
        count = 1;
        if(guess != input)
        {
            guesser();
        }
        System.out.println("It took me " + count + " tries to find " + guess + " and " + input);
    }

    public static void guesser()
    {
         boolean check = false;
         while(!check)
        {
            guess = (new Random()).nextInt(top) + 1; //Stack Overflow - null
            if(nums.contains(guess) && !(guess.equals(input)))
            {
                count--;
                guesser();
            }
           else if(guess.equals(input))
           {
                check = true;
                System.out.println("My guess was " + guess);
                // nums.add(guess);
                count++;
            }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("My guess was " + guess);
                nums.add(guess);
                count++;
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: As an aside, why are you declaring a `new Scanner` each time?  Why not just create the `Scanner` and use it twice (obviously you would need to consume the line terminator).

Comment: What is the full error message? And what line causes it?

Answer (score 5):

In `guesser()` method, you're invoking itself:

```
if(nums.contains(guess) && !(guess.equals(input)))
{
    count--;
    guesser();
}
```

There is quite a possibility it will never end. But all that is in while loop, so why not get rid of recurrence and do this in an iterative style?

Comment: When you refactor your code, I would first populate nums with several values that are higher than top and then test this as is, preferably stepping through the debugger. This will give you a failing test to develop against and make it easy to isolate and fix this behavior.

Comment: @JessicaPennell is that a comment to my answer or a question?

Comment: Sorry it's a comment toward the question, using your answer. I can't edit it now but I meant to @xXMavhawkXx

Answer (score 0):

You are making it more complicated than it needs to be and introducing recursion unnecessarily.  The recursion is the source of your stack overflow as it gets too deep before it "guesses" correctly.
There is a lot of sloppiness in there as well.  Here's a cleaned up version:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Guess {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the top number");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int top = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number to guess (1 - " + top + ")");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        if (input < 1 || input > top) {
            System.out.println("That's not in range. Aborting.");
            return;
        }

        ArrayList <Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();

        Random rng = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        while(true) {
          int guess = rng.nextInt(top) + 1;
          if (!nums.contains(guess)) {
            nums.add(guess);
            if (nums.size() == 1) {
                System.out.println("My first guess is " + guess);
            } else {
                System.out.println("My guess was " + guess);
            }
            if (guess == input) {
                System.out.println("It took me " + nums.size() + " tries to find " + guess);
                break;
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this method is based on your original algorithm and is not an optimal way to do this.  The more guesses the computer makes, the harder it is to pick a number it hasn't used already - so the loop would tend to "spin" without doing useful work.  An alternate solution is to create an array of all possible guesses, randomize it, and then simply go through it from the start until it got to the correct number.

Answer (score 0):

OK - a different approach to your `guesser` for fun.  Enumerate a randomized sequence of numbers in specified range (1 to 'top') and find the `guess` in the list whose index is effectively the number of "attempts" and return.

(BTW - @Andronicus answer is the correct one.)

```
/** Pass in 'guess' to find and 'top' limit of numbers and return number of guesses. */
public static int guesser(int guess, int top) {
    List<Integer> myNums;
    Collections.shuffle((myNums = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, top).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())), new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()));        
    return myNums.indexOf(guess);
}
```